# Winqual for Mac OSX

Tags: macos, error-reporting, winqual

is there a way to see applications crashes of our mac-application like we can using error reports using Microsoft's WinQual for windows applications?

Thank you!

Regards
Uwe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds to me like you want [Smart Crash Reports.](http://smartcrashreports.com/)

Apple's [Crash Reporter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crash_Reporter_%28Mac_OS_X%29) has no mechanism to give the original developer the reports that are sent to Apple, although presumably large software companies with high level developer agreements with Apple will be able to access statistics about them.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, but Console.app (located under Applications/Utilities by default) will show debug output from your application and others.

Apple also had some sort of crash reporter, but I don't know how to turn that feature on.

Comment: I know that you can submit crash reports to apple. But how does the vendor of a certain application get to these reports? There must be some sort of "platform" to grab these reports from apple.

Comment: Generally when you're about to submit these crash reports, you have the option of viewing (and copying) all of that data. Said data is useful, if you know how to read it.